# How to define a Fortran subroutine with arbitrary number of arguments?

Tags: fortran

First I want to say the answer is not about something like `optional` or `present`.

I want to define a function that looks like `write(*,*) ...`. As we see, the number of input variants can be arbitrary. If we use the `optional` keyword, we need to define all the possible inputs. Assume that we have 1000 (possible) inputs, what can we do?

Comment: IMHO - Having more that one or two optional parameters leads to bad design. For uniform type parameters it is recommended to use arrays, even if they created of the fly, like `addnode( [1,2,3,4] )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do anything with simple subroutine or Fortran arguments. It is simply not possible. You can only use arguments that are defined in the function.

You will have to either place everything into an array, if the types of all inputs are the same, or you will have to create some more complicated derived types - maybe a polymorphic linked list or similar.

Note that what you ask for does exist in some languages (C variadic functions, for example), but it does not exist in Fortran.

Comment: Just to add - there are things in the Fortran language that can't be replicated by user procedures. Closer to what you're asking for, the MIN and MAX functions can have an arbitrary number of arguments, each with names, but there's no way for you to write something similar.